Should I squash other people commits in my PR?
let say there are 2 authors, red and blue, I have this git log file
git log --oneline
a123bc Red
a123bd Red
a123be Red
a123bf Blue
a123bg Red
There are 5 logs, I want to squash the commits made by red into 1 commit. but I don't want to touch blue one.
so I git rebase -i HEAD~4
I sqaush the 3 commits and pick the 1 commit that i want. s === squash, p === pick
s a123bc Red
s a123bd Red
s a123be Red
? a123bf Blue <== I don't know what to do here
p a123bg Red

What should i choose for the blue author commit? I want to leave blue commits and merge all the changes I made into my own commit. The one I choose p for
Should I pick the blue one?  I think all the changes I made in squashes commits will goes into blue one if I also pick blue one.
Can someone suggest me a solution.

You can reorder commits by moving them around in the interactive rebase editor. You can move the other author's commit after the squash list. You may have to resolve conflicts by hand if you change the order of commits.

I also don't like to squash other people's commits into mine, so when I'm in this situation I usually do one of these:

If I can reorder my commits without conflicts, I'll just do that so I can squash all of mine into 1 commit while keeping the other person's commit.
If I can't do #1, and before and after are worth keeping I'll just end up with 3 commits (before, other person's, after).
If the other person's commit is relatively minor, I'll just squash it into my commit and then give them credit in the trailer of the commit message:

Co-authored-by: First Last <email@email.com>

(Just copy the name and email exactly as is from the other person's commit.)

There is no way to squash all four commits labelled "Red" into a single commit without also moving the order of the "Blue" commit to come either before or after all the "Red" commits.
But, to take a step back here, if your feature branch above is destined to be merged into the source branch anyway, there is not much motivation to even do this rework on the feature branch.  Most likely, going forward, the contribution from the feature branch will only live on in the source/reference branch as as single merge commit.  The exact original structure of the feature branch may not be important.

You're assuming a particular merge process here, but there's no reason to expect OP's project to squash merge PRs. Many projects clean up the commit history in the PR branch before merging with a Merge commit or a Rebase merge.
